# оператор разрешения области видимости (::) к типу

Tags: c++

Какой синтаксис использовать при выводе типа вида

```cpp
template <class T>
using Type = std::remove_pointer_t<std::vector<T>*>::value_type;
```

чтобы Type == T
Желательно одним стейтментом.

Текущая запись выдаёт ошибку С2061.

Comment: template <class T>    using Type  =  ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если таким способом хотите выразить: `template <class T> using Type = T;`, то:

```
template <class T>
using Type =  typename std::remove_pointer_t<std::vector<T>*>::value_type;
```

Потому что  нужно указывать что такое `Т`, и `std::remove_pointer_t<std::vector<T>*>` это фактически  `std::vector<T>`, а еще нужно указывать, что  зависимое имя `value_type`,  является именем типа.